# Replace a line in a text file if it matches a pattern

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to loop a specific file and see if any line contains a certain word or text and I want to replace the whole line. I am not sure how I am suppose to do it.

Right now this what I have:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("C:\folder\myfile.properties") DO (
  Set Line="transaction.sic.lettreEnvironnementBackend"
   IF %%G == %Line% (
      replace that line with new text
   )
)

pause
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Line=transaction.sic.lettreEnvironnementBackend"
(
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("C:\folder\myfile.properties") DO (
   IF "%%G"=="%Line%" (
      echo replacement line
   ) else (echo %%G)
)
)>replacement_filename

pause
endlocal
```

Note that the replacement filename should not be the source filename. Once tested, `move` the replacement file to the original filename if required.

Note also that the instruction will exactly match the contents of `line` - there's no allowance for any other characters on the line.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

Comment: it recreate et new file but doesn't echo anything from the IF ELSE statement

Comment: what is in the new file? Please note that batch can be very sensitive to layout. It's best to cut-and-paste the code. Using a word-processor often changes the code to make it seem more "normal text" - it may replace the quotes with "smart quotes" for instance. At a stretch, use `notepad` but better to use a text editor like `editplus` or `notepad++`

Answer (score 0):

Also easy in PowerShell.

```
Get-Content .\OutputFile.txt |
    % { if ($_ -eq 'Warning message') { 'NEW WARNING' } else { $_ } }
```